# read.demogdata from demography package, import data from an object?

Tags: r

I am using the `read.demogdata` in the [demography package in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/demography/demography.pdf) to format data for life expectancy calculations.

The example in the package is this:

```
read.demogdata(file, popfile, type, label, max.mx = 10, skip = 2,
popskip = skip, lambda, scale=1)
```

Where `file` and `popfile` are `.txt` files.   I would like to keep my tables as objects in R rather than creating a million text files and saving them in a folder. Does anyone know a way to create an object that could be read like a `txt` file in the R environment or another workaround for this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using `.csv` formats with the `demography` package?

Comment: I have not. The documentation says it requires a .txt file. I am currently looking into the function demogdata(). I think this might be the solution to read objects and create the demography object.